# Java Isn't Displaying gui right

Tags: java, ubuntu, user-interface, jframe

I have a simple gui and when I run is it is perfect, but occasionally it doesn't display right. I have a circle in a JPanel. When it runs right it displays in the middle for the JFrame like I intended it to, but when it does not work right the circle appears closer to the bottom of the screen. How can I fix this so it displays right each time? Is my code incorrect (I hope not! :) ), or is it some bug in java. So here is my code:

**Update:** It seems that the window height is changing.

Run.java--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Run {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Window w = new Window();
        w.setSize(800, 500);
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Window.java----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window() {
        super("Wheel");
        Gui g = new Gui();
        add(g);
    }
}
```

Gui.java--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui extends JPanel {
    private Color wheelColor = new Color(0, 0, 255);

    public Gui() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(wheelColor);
        g.fillOval(40,  40, 420, 420);
    }
}
```

Also I'm using Ubuntu, I don't know if that would affect it at all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a layout manager (particularly for your Window class), which will help your components display in a more predictable manner.

Comment: Can you add a few screenshots? Nonetheless it's weird that it doesn't behave deterministically. Usually this means a threading issue, i.e., sometimes it finishes drawing the canvas before it starts drawing the circle, other times it does not. Or you could be doing something different when the circle's in the wrong place. The latter might be more likely since I'm pretty sure Swing is single-threaded, though.

Comment: I don't have enought rep to post images, :(.

Comment: @user3131261 - add the links and someone with the rep will edit them into embedded pictures for you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you create the UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.
2. Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` within the `paintComponent` method before you do any custom painting, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details
3. Don't rely on magic numbers, the size of the window is the size of it's content + its frame decorations.  You should get using `getWidth` and `getHeight` to determine the size of the `Gui` panel and overriding `getPreferredSize` to allow the window to determine how much room it needs to (optimally) display it

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Window w = new Window();
                w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                w.pack();
                w.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                w.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Window extends JFrame {

        public Window() {
            super("Wheel");
            Gui g = new Gui();
            add(g);
        }
    }

    public static class Gui extends JPanel {

        private Color wheelColor = new Color(0, 0, 255);

        public Gui() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(440, 440);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(wheelColor);
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int x = (width - 420) / 2;
            int y = (height - 420) / 2;
            g.fillOval(x, y, 420, 420);
        }
    }
}
```

Also beware of naming your classes after classes that already exist within the default API, `java.awt.Window` already exists and can cause confusion not only for yourself, but for other developers ;)